# Merging the Next Fortify Scan with an Existing Scan using the Maven Fortify Plugin

Tags: java, maven, fortify

The translate and scan goals are working for the projects we are scanning.

But we are still doing the merging manually; i.e. we set aside the last scan .fpr file and run the scan again via Maven and then use the Fortify Workbench to merge the two .fpr files.

How is merging a previous scan with the current scan for a project done, using the Maven Fortify plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Maven plugin is a wrapper on sourceanalyzer utility. It can not merge FPR's.

Option 1: Using Fortify SSC. When you upload your result file, SSC will merge of it and the latest one on the server.

Option 2: Using fprutility from the SCA package.

```
Usage:
    -merge -project myProject.fpr -source myAuditedProject.fpr -f output.fpr
```

You can use [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) to invoke it.